# How can I pass a parameter to this function?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have the following code:

```
[replyAllBtn addTarget:self.target action:@selector(ReplyAll:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

- (void)replyAll:(NSInteger)tid {
// some code
}
```

How can I send a parameter to the `ReplyAll` function?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The replyAll method should accept (id)sender. If a UIButton fired the event, then that same UIButton will be passed as the sender. UIButton has a property "tag" that you can attach your own custom data to (much like .net winforms).

So you'd hook up your event with:

```
[replyAllBtn addTarget:self.target action:@selector(ReplyAll:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
replyAllBtn.tag=15;
```

then handle it with:

```
(void) ReplyAll:(id)sender{
    NSInteger *tid = ((UIControl*)sender).tag;
    //...
```

Comment: hey thanx this is exactly wht i wanted ...... 

adding the tag works fine , but in the Controller , where the replyAll func is defined 

{
NSInteger *tid = (*NSInteger)sender.tag;
}

gives an error saying "request for member tag in something not a structure or union " 

:(

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up, Rob. I was trying to figure out exactly how I was going to accomplish the same behavior Vijayeta was seeking. @Vijayeta: The sender is the button itself, so I believe you need to try "( ( UIControl * )sender ).tag;". Note that you have to enclose the cast object in parentheses before you can access the tag property.

Comment: @Vijayeta: `.tag` is an integer, not a pointer to an integer. `NSInteget tid = sender.tag`

Answer (score 2):

A selector function will normally be defined as such:

```
- (void) ReplyAll:(id)sender;
```

So the only parameter an action will ever receives is the actual control that called it.
You could just add a property to your control that can be read in replyAll

Comment: Hii, Thanx for the prompt reply , one doubt tht i have is , since the control is an instance of UIButton , how can i add any property to it ??? 
May be the question is to naive ... but i dont really get it .

Answer (score 2):

If you want to send an int value, set the tag of the button = the int value you want to pass. Then you can access the tag value of the button to get the int you wanted.

NSInteger is not a pointer. Try this

```
NSInteger tid = sender.tag;
```

Comment: i have tried tht itself 

but the error is not regarding the object type , it is not geting the type of the sender . thats y the error says "request for member tag in something not a structure or union"

Comment: Is the sender an object of a custom class you've declared? In that case try [sender tag] instead of sender.tag. That usually works.

Answer (score 2):

It's working now  :D.

```
{
NSInteger tid = [sender tag];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The MVC model used in Cocoa works differently. Basically, the idea is that a control (=view) such as a button only lets a function know it was pressed, not knowing what this means. The function then has to know all the dynamics and dependencies. In your case, it's the function that has to find the parameter. To accomplish that, you'll "bind" other objects to the function (= controller).

I suggest you read a few Cocoa tutorials first if you want to get ahead with iPhone programming.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few good ways to do this.  The two most commonly implemented would be to have the controller (who's receiving the action) know about possible senders, or having the sender itself have a method that you end up using to determine the proper behavior.

The first (my preferable way, but it's easy to argue the opposite) would be implemented like such:

```
@interface Controller : NSObject {
    UIButton *_replyToSender;
    UIButton *_replyToAll;
}
- (void)buttonClicked:(id)sender;
@end

@implementation Controller
- (void)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
    if (sender == _replyToSender) {
         // reply to sender...
    } else if (sender == _replyToAll) {
         // reply to all...
    }
}
@end
```

The second way would be implemented in a manner such as:

```
typedef enum {
    ReplyButtonTypeSender = 1,
    ReplyButtonTypeAll,
} ReplyButtonType;

@interface Controller : NSObject {
}
- (void)buttonClicked:(id)sender;
@end

@interface MyButton : UIButton {
}
- (ReplyButtonType)typeOfReply;
@end

@implementation Controller
- (void)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
    // You aren't actually assured that sender is a MyButton, so the safest thing
    // to do here is to check that it is one.
    if ([sender isKindOfClass:[MyButton class]]) {
        switch ([sender typeOfReply]) {
            case ReplyButtonTypeSender:
                // reply to sender...
                break;
            case ReplyButtonTypeAll:
                // reply to all...
                break;
        }
    }
}
@end
```