# how to implement addTarget property in a UIButton

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a function (for example **function1**)where I have a button and an object called auxiliarStruct, and I have that line:

```
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(userSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

But in @selector(userSelected) I need to pass as parameters an object needed in that function, but I don't know how implement it. 
I have declared that object here:

```
//UsersController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UsersController : NSObject{
    NSInteger *prof_id;
    NSString *createTime;
    NSString *fullName;
    NSString *thumb;
}

@property (nonatomic) NSInteger *prof_id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSString *createTime;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSString *fullName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSString *thumb;

@end
```

I have the called function declared like this:

```
-(void)userSelected:(id)sender{
  //CODE
}
```

I have an object of this class, called auxiliarStruct and this is that I need. I tried with

```
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(**userSelected:auxiliarStruct**)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

but it don't works
Can anyone help me? Thanks.

ps: sorry for my english, i know it's bad

Comment: what kind of parameter? Can you give an example?

Comment: an object of an own class with 4 nsstrings inside: UsersController : NSObject{
    NSInteger *prof_id;
    NSString *createTime;
    NSString *fullName;
    NSString *thumb;
}

Comment: Pfitz, I edited the question. I hope you understand it now

Comment: so you got an class `UserController` how do you access this class in the class where you declare the target-action method for the button ?

Comment: Not sure if you understand me well. I just want to pass a variable as a parameter to the function userSelected through addTarget

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can only Pass a `(UIButton*)` object as a parameter with `addTarget @selector` method. You can set the UIButton tag and use it on the called function. You may want to find out any alternatives for sending string values.

Use the below code for passing a tag with button :

```
     btn_.tag = 10; 
    [btn_ addTarget:self action:@selector(functionName:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

The button action should look like this :

```
- (void) functionName:(UIButton *) sender {

    NSLog(@"Tag : %d", sender.tag);

}
```

Comment: Neptune, I'm trying use a tag. I have this: btn.tag = *(auxiliarStruct.prof_id); What can I do in userSelected function to obtain the correct value from auxiliarStruct.prof_id?. Now I have this line: NSInteger *userid = ((UIControl*)sender).tag; but NSLog not displays the correct value

Comment: I understand it, but I need the value of auxiliarStruct.prof_id in tag

Comment: @nanoDev Please log the value of auxiliarStruct.prof_id before setting it as button tag. auxiliarStruct.prof_id must be an integer.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if you can add parameters to the button's action, I never encountered such a method.

The closest thing we did was to select different tags to the buttons and differentiate the actions according to the tags.

Anyway, this is not exactly an answer to your question but I would suggest as an alternative to use a class property instead of sending the parameter. For example:

- you click on the button and you want to send the value "test" to your selector. Instead of sending "test" you set that class property to "test" and in your selector you read it from there. I don't know if it fits your needs 100% but I consider it to be an option.

You raise an interesting question though. I'll try and look into it in case I will need it too sometimes and if I find anything, I'll update my answer

[edit]
Apparently you are not the only one asking this question: [How can I pass a parameter to this function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/450222/855738) In this case there was also no standard solution and the tag was used.

Answer (score 1):

The event will send the button as parameter, so:

```
   -(void)userSelected:(id)sender {

           UIButton *button = sender;
           ...
    }
```