# Passing an object to selector action

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Ok simple question but can't find an answer.

I'v got a button to save information in my app. 
I have

```
  NSMutableArray *textFields = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:5];
    UITextField *textField = nil;
```

This is the information i want to save, i'v got 5 textfields in textFields mutablearray.

```
[save addTarget:self action:@selector(saveInfo)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and

```
-(void)saveInfo {
    [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue: ????? forKey:@"Phone"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

The question is how to access and get information from like textFields[1].text in my saveInfo void ?

Ok To get things a little bit clearer i'v added the whole class. its not very big, and maybe someone could see thats the problem with my implementation .

```
@implementation Settings

- (id)init: (TableViewController*) TableControll {
  NSMutableArray *textFields = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:5];
    UITextField *textField = nil;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f+(i*35), 120.0f, 30.0f)];
        textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [textField setBorderStyle:(UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect)];
        [TableControll.view addSubview:textField];

        [textFields addObject:textField];
        [textField release]; textField = nil;
    }
    UITextField *textName = textFields[0];
    textName.placeholder = @"Vardas";

    UITextField *textNo = textFields[1];
    textNo.placeholder = @"Telefonas";
    textNo.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
    UITextField *textPin = textFields[2];
    textPin.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
    textPin.placeholder = @"Pin";

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(150, 20, 160, 30);
    [button setTitle:@"Advanced settings" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [TableControll.view addSubview:button];
    UIButton *save = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    save.frame = CGRectMake(150, 60, 160, 30);
    [save setTitle:@"Save settings" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [TableControll.view addSubview:save];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(goAdvanced)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [save addTarget:self action:@selector(saveInfo)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return self;
}

-(void)goAdvanced {
    AppDelegate *newControll = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    [newControll ChangeController];
}

-(void)saveInfo {

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
        UITextField *tempTxtField=[_textFields objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"do it %@",tempTxtField.text);
    }

}

@end
```

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450222/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-to-this-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you'd want to do if you are using interface builder is create a bunch of `IBOutlet` for your textfields instead of keeping them in an array. Check out this: [tutorial](http://oleb.net/blog/2011/06/creating-outlets-and-actions-via-drag-and-drop-in-xcode-4/)

Now it looks like you're creating things by hand, so in this case, you probably just want to declare your array as `@property` so it can be accessed by your save method.

Comment: I'v tried using property, but i still can't get it done. Though textFields become visible to save method. But this still prints null eventhrough i am certain there is data in textname.text >>    UITextField *textName = _textFields[0];
    NSLog(@"Data: %@", textName.text);

Comment: What does `NSLog(@"Data: %d, %@", [_textFields count], textName);` display?

Answer (score 0):

To access the `text` property of a `UITextField` from your array you would write:

```
((UITextField *)[textFields objectAtIndex:1]).text
```

Comment: This method is great, but it returns null while i try to print it in saveInfo method.. Maybe you could tell why it happens?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the all textfield,

```
  for(int i=0;i<[textFields count];i++) {
    UITextField *tempTxtField=[textFields objectAtIndex:i];
    NSlog(@"%@",tempTxtField);
}
```

Comment: Intresting.. tried your method but app doesn't even get to the cycle, even through I am certain textFields aren't empty. How can this be

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)saveInfo {
    NSMutableArray *tempArr = [NSMutableArray array];
    for(int i = 0; i < [textFieldsArray count]; i++){
        [tempArr addObject:[(UITextField*)[textFieldsArray objectAtIndex:i]text]];
    }
    [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:tempArr forKey:@"Phone"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

Comment: Sorry. it says property text not found on an object type id

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand your question, but this is what I would do in your place.  Instead of creating an array to hold each of the textfields, I'd just assign them a custom tag.  Any number will work  (although avoid zero since that's the default tag on all views).  So your init method would look like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f+(i*35), 120.0f, 30.0f)];
    textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    textField.tag = (i+1);
    [textField setBorderStyle:(UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect)];
    [TableControll.view addSubview:textField];
    [textField release]; textField = nil;
}
```

Then in the code that you want to reference the text field, you'd retrieve the view by its tag, making sure to cast it as UITextField.

-(void)saveInfo {

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
    UITextField *textField = nil;
    UIView *view = [self.view viewsWithTag:i];
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
        textField = (UITextField *) view;
        NSLog(@"do it %@",textField.text)
    }

}
```

}

NOTE:  I'm referencing self.view but you'll  need to reference TableControll.view.  You'll need to retain a reference to it somewhere in your code.  Also, I'd recommend your start using ARC.

Hope that helps!  Good luck!